# Google Cloud Platform: Uptime Check / Response Validation "403(Forbidden)"

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-monitoring

Trying to get Google to validate the output of my "Cloud-Function" in the "Response-Validation" for "Uptime-Checks".

I've used "regex" to try to validate my "Json" output but it doesn't work, when I test it I get: "Responded with "403 (Forbidden)" in 219 ms."

below is an example of what my "Source" is in the "Cloud-Function":

```
def example(request):
from flask import request, jsonify
import requests

postdata = {
  "zzz": ["zzz"],
  "zzz": ["zzz"],
  "zzz": "zzz",
  "zzz": {"distinct": True}
}

posturl = 'zzz'
requestheaders = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Api-Key': 'zzz'}
r = requests.post(url=posturl, json=postdata, headers=requestheaders)
result = r.json()
return(result)
```

Comment: What is `posturl`? Do you have permission to `POST` to it?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved:

- It was a permissions issue in the "IAM", due to the "Cloud Functions" and the "Monitoring/UptimeCheck" being in different projects.

How I tested it:

- When I changed the functions "Authentication" to "Allow unauthenticated" which is open to the public, my regex in the "Response Content" worked

Sidenote:

- make sure your "Path" under the "Target" tab in the "Uptime Check" is correct, look at the "URL ?" which is under "Path" to make sure you got the correct url.